# How to view logs of a renamed directory?

Tags: git, git-log

Suppose I have a repository with this directory structure:

```
my-projects
├── .git
├── project-a
│   ├── sun.hs
│   └── rain.hs
└── project-b
    ├── earth.ml
    └── moon.ml
```

To view all changes I made to `project-a`, I can do `git log --oneline project-a`:

```
646fe67 Add rain.hs
752a061 Change color of sun
9edcc0c Add sun.hs
```

So far, this is all good. But suppose I now rename the `project-a` directory to `project-1`:

```
git mv project-a project-1
git commit -m 'Rename project-a to project-1'
```

To view the logs of `project-1` (the former `project-a`), I do `git log --oneline project-1`:

```
82442bb (HEAD -> master) Rename project-a to project-1
```

Oh no! It doesn't show the changes I made to `sun.hs` and `rain.hs`! This output would have been a lot more useful:

```
82442bb (HEAD -> master) Rename project-a to project-1
646fe67 Add rain.hs
752a061 Change color of sun
9edcc0c Add sun.hs
```

But how can I accomplish that? i.e. How do I show the complete logs of a renamed directory?

I know that `git log --follow project-1/sun.hs` correctly shows the log for a file, but that's only for one file. When used on a directory, the `--follow` option has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cant.

Git doesn't store folder names, it stores the file path so you cant track folder renames.

What you can do is to write a script which will do it.

for example:

- loop over file names in the desired folder
- use `git log --follow -- <file name>`